# What does "Can you drive" mean?

Tags: word-usage

I know when we say "Can you...?", it represents you have the ability to do something.
But there is a situation:
Amy has drunk a lot of alcohol, and she wants to go home.
Bob asked her:"Can you drive?"
He means if Amy can go home on her own and avoid a car accident.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You've got the main meaning, but let me be a bit more precise...

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**can**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can)

> to be able to

Amy may **know how to drive**, she has the ability to drive but **she is not able at that specific** **moment** to drive **safely** because she is drunk.

Also, the question does not imply that she can go home **on her own**. Bob and Amy may have shared the car, but it's her car, she is supposed to drive both of them home.

Comment: I think a key word in this context is “safely”. Our inebriated Amy is able to drive, but not able to drive **safely**. It’s unstated but implied in the question.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the edit. My bad, we got that verb in Spanish.

Comment: It would make a great verb; too bad we haven’t adopted it in English yet. The best I can think of is [_fine-tune_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/fine-tune), which is much clunkier.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation both were aware that Amy was drunk to some extent, so the version 'Can you...' worked and couldn't be mixed up with the idea that Amy *didn't (know how to) drive a car*. A more specific question, clear without any *context*, could be:

> Are you in a condition to drive?